# NLog issue inserting logs to DATABASE after upgrading .NET 5 to .NET 6 and NLOG

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, nlog

I have the following in my
**CSPROJ file**

```
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Config" Version="4.7.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Database" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
```

This is exactly how I have my project setup. [how to implement NLOG](https://code-maze.com/writing-logs-to-sql-server-using-nlog/)

Just additionally I am also storing Logs in File like so:

```
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileTarget" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

The file gets the logs however the database receives nothing. It was working prior to upgrade from .NET 5 to 6 and upgraded NLOG. Anyone know of any changes that I am unaware of?

Internal errors gives me nothing but it forwarded the logs to both file and database.

```
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Trace] => dbTarget
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Debug] => dbTarget
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Info] => dbTarget
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Warn] => dbTarget fileTarget
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Error] => dbTarget fileTarget
2022-09-07 08:41:53.3680 Debug Logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator [Fatal] => dbTarget fileTarget
```

Comment: There were lots of breaking changes in the transition to NLog 5.0. Have you read the [NLog 5.0 - List of major changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html) page?

Comment: I did see it, I can't pin point what would be something that impacts the database entry only. As I mentioned, I still receive logs to file.

Comment: I created a new project upgraded it to 5.x and no issues there. Something is with this project that is the issue.

Comment: Are you using `<targets async="true">` and have forgotten to [flush](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#Best-practices-for-using-NLog) by calling `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` on application-exit ? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue,

In my case, I add Nlog.DataBase from nuget management

and log can write to database well

Do not need modify any settings